# Can I use Hudson installed on OSX to run MSBuild on a Windows Server?

Tags: .net, macos, windows-phone-7, msbuild, hudson

I'm not familiar with Hudson or OSX, I'm just trying to find out if this is possible. We have a Hudson instance installed on OSX. We want to use the build process to connect to a Windows Server and execute a batch file that runs MSBuild for our WP7 project. I don't have access to the Hudson machine and my searches so far haven't resulted in any answers, though my hunch is that this is not possible.

End goal: Our Hudson machine runs OSX and we want to know if it is possible to use our Hudson to build a Windows Phone 7 project. We have a machine running Windows Server 2008, but it doesn't have Hudson. We want to have one Hudson machine that does all the builds if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes this is possible.  You can setup the Hudson instance on the mac osx machine as the master and you can have the windows server machine setup as a slave.  Then when configuring your project you can select which slave to execute your build on.  Here is a link to the hudson wiki on distributed builds. http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds